# How to use disk quota in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, quota

I want to use linux quota in rails app to limit user's space usage on disk. But my current implementation will save users' attachments as they are owned by which one who start up rails app. Do I need to create every users on linux server and assign them a disk quota?

So, is there any rails plugin/gems allow me to do this? And what is github solution? They did not only limit the size of attachments but also user's git repositories. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to limit user's disk space usage on application level, without the use of OS-level tools.

As a simple example, add `disk_quota` and `current_disk_usage` fields to user model, update  `current_disk_usage` after each successful file upload. Before each file upload, throw an exception if uploaded file size + `current_disk_usage` > `disk_quota`.

This is much more versatile and cross-platform approach. This way you are not limiting yourself to using Linux OS, can store your files and your application server(s) on different machines, can store your files on Amazon S3, etc. Plus, it's much more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but my problem is that I want to host other services such as git repository. So I can not limit repository disk usage if I just do something on app level.

Comment: There are some git gems out there that incapsulate git repo creation/interaction (not sure if any of them has a method to get total repository size; anyway, they can be extended to support this method). Getting repository size from rails can be done 1) on a low level: `du -s repo_dir`, then parsing the output 2) using ruby methods like File.size('repo_dir'), etc. Check repo file size after each repo file change (or periodically if there are changes, to avoid overhead), compare user's repo size + his other files' size to his quota and throw exception if quota is exceeded.